# get copy of older version of git repo

Tags: git

We have an evolving git repo. I want to compare the current state of the repo to a milestone I achieved several months ago. How can I get a local copy of the older state of the repo, without doing any harm/damage to the current state of the repo?

I see some option that seem promising ("checkout", "reset current branch"), but I want to be careful not accidentally revert the main branch for everyone.

Comment: This is one of the most basic Git tasks you can perform, and reading any Git tutorial would have shown you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check an older state of the repo by checking out an older commit. Every commit comes with a commit hash which you can utilize. For example if you do `git log` you will get a list of all commits in the repo. Checkout your desired commit by doing `git checkout [commit hash]` where [commit hash] is the desired hash.

In order to get back to the most recent commit just do `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's some misunderstanding about how git works...

First the good news:  As long as you work with a clone (which you almost certainly always are) it is very unlikely that you'll change the main branch "for everyone".  All you have to do to ensure you don't: refrain from `push`ing main.  You can do whatever you want to a clone of the repository and it doesn't matter.  If you're *really* worried, then clone the repo and in that clone `git remote remove origin`, and now you'd really have to go out of your way to change anything about the origin repo at all.

But now as to reverting to an earlier state and comparing... it's not very clear what you're trying to do.

You said revert the *repository* to an older state; for the most part, as a repo evolves you're just adding objects to it and updating branch refs.  So if you mean that you archived the git repo (including the database; i.e. the entire .git folder, or an entire bare repo) and want to compare your current git repo against it... I wouldn't think of it as straightforward and would need to know more about what you want to accomplish.  (And unless there have been history rewrites you want to analyze, it doesn't seem like there's much you *could* accomplish along these lines...)

But you also talk about the checkout command and resetting branches.  Those have to do with *using* the database to revert the index and work tree to an older state.  And if what you want is just to compare your current work tree to an older one, that's quite easy: just use `git diff`